Why is every error in my ts code reported twice by both @typescript-eslint and eslint?
Every error in my typescript code will be reported twice by both @typescript-eslint and eslint. Like following:

It seems that my eslint is using two rules at the same time, how to fix it?
I'm using vscode extension ESLint and prettier.
My package.json file:
"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue-scoped-css": "^2.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4",
  },

My .eslintrc file
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:vue-scoped-css/base",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "defineProps": "readonly",
    "defineEmits": "readonly"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-continue": "off",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "guard-for-in": "off",

    "import/extensions": "off",
    "import/no-unresolved": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "import/first": "off", // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser/issues/58
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "vue/first-attribute-linebreak": 0,

    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off" 
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.vue"],
      "rules": {
        "vue/component-name-in-template-casing": [2, "kebab-case"],
        "vue/require-default-prop": 0,
        "vue/multi-word-component-names": 0,
        "vue/no-reserved-props": 0,
        "vue/no-v-html": 0,
        "vue-scoped-css/enforce-style-type": ["error", { "allows": ["scoped"] }]
      }
    }
  ]
}



Does this answer your question? Both ESLint and TypeScript report duplicate warnings in VSCode

If you use the recommended typescript rule I don't think you need to use the airbnb recommended rules as well because those are for JavaScript (not an answer to the question just my personal opinion)

@Arkellys
My typescript also gives errors, so strictly speaking I have three error messages for each error. But my goal is not to disable a certain rule, but to make sure that @typescript-eslint and eslint only report one error, otherwise vscode will always show twice(I don‘t know why typescript errors are not counted) the number of errors in the ts file as the correct number.

@apokryfos This configuration file was generated by someone else, and I don't know whether all the configuration items in it are necessary.

From what I see the rule no-unused-vars is in the airbnb recommended rules and also in the typescript eslint recommended rules. The typescript rule extends the base eslint rule so it should the be only one used when using typescript. If you only use TypeScript then I suggest removing line "eslint-config-airbnb-base", from your eslint configuration as the airbnb rules are mostly for JavaScript not TypeScript and typescript-eslint has its own recommendations.

@apokryfos After tried, vscode still shows twice(from @typescript-eslint and eslint) the number of errors in the ts file as the correct number.

You have two rules enabled that both do roughly the same thing:

no-unused-vars: from ESLint itself ("ESLint core")
@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars: an extension to that rule that makes it also works with TypeScript code

Per https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/#how-to-use, you'll want to disable the core no-unused-vars in your config.
  "rules": {
    // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
  }

